# jquery mobile sort button that displays a dialog with a select picker

Tags: css, html, sorting, jquery-mobile

I was using skyscanner app yesterday, and on the results page there is a 'sort' option which I want to replicate.

You click a button in footer navbar, which then loads up a dialog, with a list of options you can then scroll through to select. The dialog is an overlay on the same page.

I have attached a screenshot:

[image]

How would you do this? Probably simple but in new to jQuery mobile and just learning it.

Answer (score 0):

a solution could be to use a popup, [see the docu here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html)
for example the [popup menu](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html#popupMenu)

[image]